# why in a django app my css file in the browser sources is empty?

Tags: django, static

1. I have build a web application (using Django).
2. in the settings.py:

   ```
   STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static_in_pro","static_root")
   STATIC_DIRS=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static_in_pro","our_static")
   STATICFILES_FINDERS=["django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
   "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder"]
   ```
3. in my template `base.html`:

   ```
   link href="{% static 'css/main.css'%}" rel="stylesheet"
   link href="{% static 'css/navbar-static-top.css'%}" rel="stylesheet"
   ```
4. when i use "collectstatic", all static files are copied correctly.
5. but when i runserver, it doesnt apply statics, actualy the main.css in the browser sources is empty!
   what is the problem?

Comment: Did you try adding the full app path into the template? I mean App/Static/Templates/blabla

Comment: for DIRS?no. how should i use it exactly?

Comment: oops, it looks in "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\admin\admin\css" for statics :( . what is the problem?

Comment: Oh, you are on windows :/, seems like recursive error there, it shouldn't look for them in the Django system folder :/

Answer (score 0):

Static files are intended to be served by web-server (NGINX is perfect for this). So when doing development Django's dev server has to serve them for you, because there's no real web-server. But by default Django doesn't do that, so you have to add code to your URLconf like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

See more in the docs: [Managing static files during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development).